# Mostrar boton habilitado despues de elegir la opción de un select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un combobox, y dos botones 
los nombrare combo1, boton uno y boton dos...
lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: de inicio el combobox estara activado o visible, el boton dos y tres deberan de mostrarse inhabilitados.
cuando se seleccione una o mas opciones del combo uno se debera mostrar habilitado el boton 1 y hasta que se de click en el boton 1 se debera habilitar el boton 2
Este es el codigo hasta el momento Necesito javascript o jquery para agregar la funcionalidad...

```
  select#combo1(multiple='multiple', style='display: inline-block;margin-left: 10px;')

  button#btn2.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Boton uno
  button#btn3.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Boton dos
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo añade a tus botones disabled='disabled'

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" disabled="disabled"></button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn3" disabled="disabled"></button>
```

Ahora que ya están bloqueados con jquery puedes utilizar

```
function activarPrimerBoton() {
  if (!$("#btn2").hasClass("Activo")) {
   $("#btn2").addClass("Activo").prop('disabled', false);
  }
}

$("#combo1").change(function () {
  activarPrimerBoton();
});


$("#btn2").click(function() {
 if ($("#btn2").hasClass("Activo")) {
   $("#btn2").removeClass("Activo").prop('disabled', true);
   $("#btn3").addClass("Activo").prop('disabled', false);
 }
}
```

activarPrimerBoton es una función que simplemente añade la clase Activo a tu botón con id btn2 si es que ya no estaba activo, esto lo hacemos con hasClass que nos devuelve true si existe y además elimina la caracteristica disabled de tu botón.

Luego indicamos que si el valor de combo1 cambia activaremos la función activarPrimerBoton

Y ya por último le indicamos que si hacemos click en #btn2 y este contiene la clase Activo, borramos su clase Activo, desactivamos el botón y activamos el btn3

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido de gran manera :]